# Can I display html pages without a browser

Tags: android, html

I have some html pages which I want to display as an additional information section. Is the only way I can display them on the screen using uri.parse("htmlpage") and if so is there a way I can hide the url string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not clear whether the pages are web pages or not.  If they are not web pages then you can use a webview in a layout.

```
<WebView  
android:id="@+id/my_webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

and populate like this in onCreate

```
View tView = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
WebView webView = (WebView)tView;
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/EULA.html");
```

(Put the file into an "assets" folder at the top level of your project).
I think this should be easy to adapt for web pages.

Answer (score 1):

There's a limited support of HTML formatting in TextViews, but I don't think you can replicate the same behaviour as a WebView, and MANY tags will not be supported.

Although, you can always modify the TextView and control how you render HTML in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse class if you are using C#. If you are using jQuery - you can do a div.load(url) to show the html contents inside the div.